# View content inside phar created archives

Tags: php, phar

I have some .tar.gz, .tar.bzip2 and .tar files, and I would like to display their contents. Since I created them with Phar, it would make sense to try and view them trough phar, so I tried a few things.

First I tried from the php examples

```
$p = new Phar($myArchive[0], 0);
// Phar extends SPL's DirectoryIterator class
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($p) as $file) {
    // $file is a PharFileInfo class, and inherits from SplFileInfo
    echo $file->getFileName() . "\n";
    echo file_get_contents($file->getPathName()) . "\n"; // display contents;
}
```

It didn't work.

```
 $fh = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(newRecursiveDirectoryIterator('phar://'.$myArchive[0]), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($fh as $splFileInfo){
echo file_get_contents($splFileInfo->getPathname());
}
```

Did not work.

I also tried this

```
$p = new PharData($myArchive[0]);
foreach($p as $file)
{
    echo "$file";
}
```

Which strangely seems to produce some results but the output for a tar file is just strange: `phar://C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/application/archives/Shaddox/Shaddox-1433274964.tar/C:` For a .tar.gz the output is the same, except with the appended .gz at the end.

So what is a coorect way to view the content of .tar , .tar.gz and .tar.bzip2 files with Phar?

Note : `$myArchive[0]` contains the absolute path to an archive and it works fine using the zip library.

Comment: Not about using realpath?

Comment: did you replace `'coollibrary.phar'` from the docs with the path to your `.phar` ?

Comment: Ah yes, I did, I copied the example from php, oops. It gives a format not recognized error.